# Magento - Widget Development - Doesnt show up in CMS widgets list

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Can anyone list the main causes for a widget i developed doesn't show up in the New Instance Widget section of Magento CMS?

I followed this [tutorial](http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/12562-Develop-a-Magento-Widget-in-Easiest-way://), but it doesnt show up as it's supposed to, actually it doesnt show up at all.

If you think you need to see my code please just tell me.

Happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

If you have done the Magento security upgrades , you might want to white-list the widget so CMS pages can access it.